# Attempting to load images for spree frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Trying to load images through the vendor asset directory in Spree commerce.

Tried -

```
/vendor/assets/photo01.jpg
/assets/images/spree/frontend/photo01.jpg
/vendor/assets/images/spree/frontend/photo01.jpg - the actual path.
```

All that works is the non vendor directory of -

```
/assets/photo01.jpg
```

According to the documentation
https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html,
I should be using the vendor directory.

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct image asset path for Spree -

```
assets/spree/frontend/photo01.jpg
```